# Adding an extra field to already indexed data Solr

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, indexing

I have indexed approximately 1000 documents in Solr. But all of them are missing a field. I need to add a field to all these documents, and this field will have the same value for all of them. I do not have access to these documents to index them again. Is there any way to do this without re-indexing all the data again?

Comment: You can always return the same value for all documents by adding a pseudo field to each query. Let's say the new field should be named 'foo' and the value should be '42', then query would be `?q=*:*&fl=*,foo:42`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've configured your schema to store all values, no, there is no usable way to add a field to the documents without reindexing. If you all fields are stored, you can use atomic updates to add a new field for a document, so you could query Solr for the ids of all existing documents and perform an update that way.

Otherwise you're going to have to go with the suggestion from @michielvoo, and return a static value from the query string .. but then you could also just append it in your application before returning it to the user (or, you could add the field as a default value for the request handler in solrconfig.xml, so that you can edit and change it server side).